# Como criar uma aplicação sem barra de titulo?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

Pretendo criar um *app web* com um `WebView`. Como posso criar uma aplicação sem a barra de título que não seja *fullscreen*?

Comment: Sem Action Bar?

Comment: não sei o nome certo, sem a barra onde exibi o titulo do aplicativo e onde pode ter o icone para abrir o menu etc

Comment: Em qual versão do android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem várias formas, uma delas é definir usar o `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR` passando `getActionBar().hide()` na sua `Activity`:

#### Programaticamente

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
```

#### Usando windoActionBar no XML

No `res/styles.xml` você pode fazer desta forma:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

#### Utilizando recurso do tema NoActionBar

Porém também pode ser feito desta forma desativando a `ActionBar` fornecido pelo tema. A maneira mais fácil é ter o seu tema se estendem desde Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (ou a variante de luz) dentro do arquivo `res/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>
```

#### Detalhes

- [Using the App ToolBar](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar)

Answer (score 1):

Altere essa parte de seu AndroidManifest

```
   ...
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".Principal"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

O importante e essa linha:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Quando compilo o app para de funcionar

Comment: Não é por esse motivo. Verifique o log do Android Studio.